# get value from other class

Tags: java

I'm writing a game that involves rolling dice.

In the engine class, there is a method called `calculateResult`. In this method, I need to get the dice values for each player and compare them to see which player's dice sum is bigger.

I tried to use `int total=dicePair.getDice1()+dicePair.getDice2()`, it looks does not work at all.

This is the engine class which contains the method to roll the player dice.

```
public class GameEngineImpl implements GameEngine {
    public static int NUM_FACES = 6;

    Collection<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    GameEngineCallback gameEngineCallback;
    DicePair dicePair;

    public void rollPlayer(Player player, int initialDelay, int finalDelay, int delayIncrement) {
        for(int i = initialDelay; i <= finalDelay; i += delayIncrement) {
            int dice1 = (int) (Math.random() * NUM_FACES + 1);
            int dice2 = (int) (Math.random() * NUM_FACES + 1);
            DicePairImpl dicePairImpl = new DicePairImpl(dice1, dice2);
            gameEngineCallback.intermediateResult(player, dicePairImpl, this);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(initialDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        int dice1 = (int) (Math.random() * NUM_FACES + 1);
        int dice2 = (int) (Math.random() * NUM_FACES + 1);
        DicePairImpl dicePairImpl = new DicePairImpl(dice1, dice2);
        gameEngineCallback.result(player, dicePairImpl, this);
        player.setRollResult(dicePairImpl);
    }
}
```

This is the callback class which prints the dice values and total.

```
public class GameEngineCallbackImpl implements GameEngineCallback {
    public void intermediateResult(Player player, DicePair dicePair,
        GameEngine engine) {
        int dice1 = dicePair.getDice1();
        int dice2 = dicePair.getDice2();
        int total = dice1 + dice2;
        System.out.println("FINE: Player:" + player + ", intermediate result=Dice 1:" + dice1 + ",Dice2:" + dice2 + ".. Total:" + total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are rolling the dice, but you never save the dicePair. So you should probably do something like:

```
player.setRollResult(dicePairImpl);//after this line
dicePair = dicePairImpl;//save the reference
```

And then you could use `dicePair` in your `calculate` method.

Comment: So you should use `player.getRollResult()` in your calculate method?

Comment: Hi sir, i tried your way, and it finally works. Thanks, by the way, can you introduce some java books for me to read to improve my programming skills?

Comment: Start with easiest one "Head first series i.e. Head first Java" and then go with Effective java